# Jenkins: how to trigger pipeline on git tag

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment, jenkins-2

We want to use Jenkins to generate releases/deployments on specific project milestones. Is it possible to trigger a Jenkins Pipeline (defined in a Jenkinsfile or Groovy script) when a tag is pushed to a Git repository?

We host a private Gitlab server, so Github solutions are not applicable to our case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently something that is sorely lacking in the pipeline / multibranch workflow. See a ticket around this here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34395

If you're not opposed to using release branches instead of tags, you might find that to be easier. For example, if you decided that all branches that start with `release-` are to be treated as "release branches", you can go...

```
if( env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("release-") ) {
 // groovy code on release goes here
}
```

And if you need to use the name that comes after `release-`, such as `release-10.1` turning into `10.1`, just create a variable like so...

```
if( env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("release-") ) {
 def releaseName = env.BRANCH_NAME.drop(8)
}
```

Both of these will probably require some method whitelisting in order to be functional.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same desire and rolled my own, maybe not pretty but it worked...

In your pipeline job, mark that "This project is parameterized" and add a parameter for your tag. Then in the pipeline script checkout the tag if it is present.

Create a freestyle job that runs a script to:

- Checkout
- Run git describe --tags --abbrev=0 to get the latest tag.
- Check that tag against a running list of builds (like in a file).
- If the build hasn't occurred, trigger the pipeline job via a url passing your tag as a parameter (in your pipeline job under "Build Triggers" set "Trigger builds remotely (e.g. from scripts) and it will show the correct url.
- Add the tag to your running list of builds so it doesn't get triggered again.
- Have this job run frequently.

Comment: Brad, do you have these jobs in a public repo, so I can see how you implemented this freestyle job?

Comment: @JoaquimOliveira I don't have it in a repo and I can't share it verbatim (sorry). The freestyle job really just has one main thing, in the Build section I have a build step to run a powershell script (I am in Windows, and have the powershell plugin). The powershell script just implements the behavior I noted above, run the git commands and check the tag against a text file, then trigger the build via a url.

Comment: It is fine, but the issue here is, you have to put some validation for the already run build and not to trigger again for the same tag. But whenever there is being a push it triggers a build and it can not be controlled. I want build to trigger only with a push of a tag.

Comment: @hi.nitish yeah I hear you, I wanted something more automatic too, but I didn't find it so I came up with my own solution because that's what programmers do :)

Answer (score 0):

if you use multibranch pipeline, there is a discover tag. Use that plus Spencer solution